# What is the best symbol for vector/matrix transpose?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

What is the best or most popular symbol for vector/matrix transpose? I have used simply `^T`, for example `$c^T x$`.  I think it is ugly, mainly because it is a little too big compared with vector variables usually denoted by lower-case characters. Can you suggest a better one?

Comment: Why does it look ugly? Too big? Too high? Too what?

Comment: That's exactly what I use! :)

Comment: Perhaps it is too big. I usually use lower-case characters to denote vectors. With the upper-case `^T`, it looks quite ugly. But, I don't like the lower-case `^t`.

Comment: I use `M^\top`. (For orthocomplements of vector spaces, I similarly use `V^\bot`.) Using `T` or `t` as a superscript is problematic in disciplines where they are modestly likely to occur as an actual variable, especially one which might occur in an exponent. I choose `\top` and `\bot` because they are more obviously abstract symbols, and not variables.

Comment: @Chang: If "too big" is a problem, what about $c^T=c^{\scriptscriptstyle T}$. You can define a macro `\newcommand{\transpose}[1]{\ensuremath{#1^{\scriptscriptstyle T}}}` and use `\transpose{c}`. But, size isn't everything...

Comment: (Incidentally, while I am opinionated on this subject, the very fact that it is strongly subject to opinion makes it a somewhat questionable topic for a StackExchange site...)

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap I understand that there is no absolutely correct "answer" for this type of questions. If I am interested in other people's choice or taste, where should I ask? community wiki?

Comment: @Caramdir I revised the question a little. Well, because I asked about the most popular choice, wouldn't I be asking a fact, although it would be very hard to answer?

Comment: @Chang: Perhaps ask on chat? Alternatively, you can fish for ideas by searching online (as a matter of opinionated notation, no doubt people have been writing about it since at least 1995), or fish for ideas by checking out [DeTeXify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) or the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/). As for popularity being a fact, well... it's not exactly a fact of solid character.

Comment: In most cases, I just use a prime : `A'`.
Except if you already use this for derivation, I would advice for this minimalist symbol.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

It's always difficult to answer questions for "the best" or "most popular". As is mentioned, these are typically opinions. But you did say that your objection was the fact that the "T" symbol was too big. Therefore, I would recommend the `\intercal` symbol to produce a "T" which isn't so big. Also, writing the vectors and matrices in bold seems, in my opinion, to make it look a little better. Try the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\mathbf{A}^\intercal$\\
$\mathbf{c}^\intercal \mathbf{x}$\\
$c^T x$\\
$\mathbf{M}^\top$
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot from example above]

Comment: It is better to use `\mathbf` rather than `\textbf`

Comment: An even better to defin a new command in sense of logical markup, i.e. use `\vec` and define `\newcommand{\mtrx}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}` …

Comment: And even even better to use `\bm` instead of `\mathbf`. 'Cause, you know, you never know what stupidly exotic symbol you might one day use as a matrix or vector to impress your supervisor, colleague, or yourself ;) (and in fact, `\mathbf` can't even handle Greek letters which aren't that exotic after all).

Comment: This advice was great. To use `\bm`, just add the `bm` package to the preamble of the document.

Comment: I can't see any improvement by using \bm or \mathbf

Comment: How do I remember this symbol? Why is it called `\intercal`?

Comment: I don't know. [This post](http://planetmath.org/node/8095) has some information. For example, it is short for "intercalate" which is to put things into a list. It's not resolved satisfactorily.

Comment: The intercalate character is a binary operator. Using it to mean transpose seams to misuse what the character is meant for.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying there can only be one use for a symbol but that's not true. For example, \circ is listed as a binary operation, but it's also used as in 5^{\circ} to represent 5 degrees. Likewise, \times is listed as a binary operation but it's also used as R^{\times} to indicate the multiplicative group of units of ring R.

Comment: @skan :  For ordinary letters (or uppercase Greek letters), there should be no difference.  But try it with a matrix called `\alpha`.

Comment: For any future onlookers, there is a package called physics which, for some reason, mainly implements nice mathematical shortcuts. To that effect, vectors in bold can be written simply as \vb, and while the documentation is short it covers a lot of nice shortcuts to this nice output. \vb is much easier than \mathbf every time.

Comment: I sometimes use `newpxmath` which has a transpose symbol in it. Without that font, I now use `\mathop\intercal` to raise the glyph a little bit. I also do `\mkern-0.5mu` for tighter spacing.

Comment: @MaxXiong What is the command in `newpxmath`? thanks.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas \transp

Answer (score 85):

[The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf) says the following:

> Some people use a superscripted `\intercal` for matrix transpose: `A^\intercal`. (See the May 2009 comp.text.tex thread, "[raising math symbols](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/c2b11fa608d8434f/b02b8676502a1c10)", for suggestions about altering the height of the superscript.) `\top`, `T`, and `\mathsf{T}` are other popular choices.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The book I am currently citing a formula from uses exactly what latex produces with ``\mathbf{w}^\top`` for a transposed vector. So I am going to go with this variant... (``\intercal`` would be the second choice, but ``T`` and ``mathsf{T}`` look ugly in my opinion)

Comment: I agree with those who suggest \intercal
It looks like the traditional T for transpose, but at the same time it is not confused with the exponents. I am using it in my Tex-files.

Answer (score 58):

In order to give some reference:

(DIN) EN ISO 80000-2:2013 writes it like the following.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\newcommand*{\matr}[1]{\mathbfit{#1}}
\newcommand*{\tran}{^{\mkern-1.5mu\mathsf{T}}}
\newcommand*{\conj}[1]{\overline{#1}}
\newcommand*{\hermconj}{^{\mathsf{H}}}

\begin{document}
\[\matr{A}\tran\]   

\[\matr{A}\hermconj\coloneqq(\conj{\matr{A}})\tran\]
\end{document}
```

The good part here is that the 'big' T visually fits to the H of the same size which might be used for the Hermitian conjugate matrix.

[image]

Answer (score 45):

I prefer `A^\mathsf{T}` which looks clean and is the right size.

In my opinion, the serifs in `A^T` distracting, the T is set too low in `A^\intercal`, the T in `A^\top` is too thin and too big, and `A^*` implies the presence of complex numbers.

In any case, it's always good to use a macro in case you change your mind later.

Answer (score 33):

The symbol `\intercal` is quite a nice symbol for transpose, but it is placed a little low. Therefore the example defines `\transpose` to use a `\intercal`, which is shifted to the baseline. The symbol size adapts to the current math style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\transpose}{%
  {\mathpalette\@transpose{}}%
}
\newcommand*{\@transpose}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \raisebox{\depth}{$\m@th#1\intercal$}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  \[
    \mathbf{M}^{#1}
    \;
    \scriptstyle \mathbf{M}^{#1}
    \;
    \scriptscriptstyle \mathbf{M}^{#1}
  \]
}

\begin{document}
  \test{\transpose}
  \test{\intercal}
  \test{\mathsf{T}}
  \test{\top}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 23):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin[document}
$A^T\ A^{\mathsmaller T}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17):

Personally I often use the conjugate transpose instead. For real matrices this concept coincides with the transpose, for matrices over the complex field the conjugate is usually what you want anyway. The conjugate transpose of a matrix `A` is denote `A^*`.

Answer (score 15):

I use the pre-exponent t in upright shape, either with mathtools package, based on the code:
`\prescript{\mathrm t}{}{A}`, or using the `\ltrans` command from `leftidx` package.
Here is a code that tries to take into account different situations, which involve different math kerning, nested transpose, and so on. I define a `\transp` command, with an optional argument, the math kerning (defaults to `-3mu`) between the t prescript and the ‘prescripted’ expression that follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\transp}[2][-3mu]{\ensuremath{\mskip1mu\prescript{\smash{\mathrm t\mkern#1}}{}{\mathstrut#2}}}%

\begin{document}

Matrix transposition has the following properties :
  \begin{align*}
\transp{(\mskip-1mu AB)} & = \transp{B}\transp{A} \\
\transp{(\transp{A})} & = A \\
\transp{(\mathrm N + \mathrm P)} & = \transp[0mu]{\mathrm N} +\transp[0mu]{\mathrm P}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: A rendering of the above LaTeX code]

Comment: Could you give a complete MWE?

Comment: It is the first time I see the transpose as a presuperscript. Did you see it before. It is an interesting idea though to separate exponentiation and transposition (which commute for matrices).

Comment: @alfC: It's a traditional notation in French mathematical typography. Not the only one: there's also t or T as superscripts, but always in `upright` shape.

Comment: @Sean Alfred: I had forgotten to add a full example. This is done now, and the code has been modified.

Answer (score 8):

Conjugate transpose is in physics often denoted by `^\dagger` because of its association with adjoint operators.

Answer (score 6):

There are some good suggestions regarding which symbol to use, it is a good idea to define your own macros for indicating matrices, vectors, and transpose, so that you can write:

```
\MAT A \VEC b^\TRANSPOSE
```

This will make it easy to change the notation in the future, if you ever need to do so. In addition, the source is more readable than `\mathbf A \mathbf b^\intercal` etc.

Answer (score 5):

maybe you could use `$\mathbf{C}^{^\mathrm{T}}$` to raise it a smaller transpose T[image: it produces this]

Answer (score 3):

`A^{\tau}` looks best for me.
I tried others but T was still too big.