# What is the meaning of the name of the \intercal symbol?

Tags: symbols, tex-history, meaning

I've noticed that the `\intercal` symbol is popular for denoting the transpose of a matrix, which is all good and fine (and something I've adopted as I agree, it looks slick).

But if this symbol were intended for matrix transposes I can't help but suspect it would have won the name `\transpose`, which it doesn't have.

So I'm curious what this symbol actually is intended for, what it means, where the name comes from, what it evokes etc.? I've look long and hard on-line fueled by the passion of failure in a sense. A classic example of useless I found here:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tex_commands/intercal.htm

Well that explains it! Not!

On-line searches are confounded by the programming language of the same name. And I have found the symbol on any number of mathematical symbol lists but never explained beyond its name. The intercal symbol.

So I'm curious. What exactly is the `\intercal` symbol? What does the name mean? What is its history and where is it used (other than for matrix transposes)?

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic, U+224b has full name INTERCALATE and has been in Unicode since (at least) 1.1 so was probably inherited from one of the code sets that were lumped in to the standard, the name intercal comes from iso879 isoamsb, the original sgml math character entity set. various on line dictionaries have meanings for intercalate in calendars and chemistry but I don't see any of them used with the T like symbol in this slot, so I have no idea. I would guess it's just used for transpose as a substitute bold sans serif T

Comment: not sure this question is entirely on topic here, but identifying the origin of the name probably is.  i have always assumed it is short for "intercalation", the insertion of something into an existing structure.  that term (though i have never seen the symbol used in that context) was important in the creation of tables of the values of functions, a task now made pretty much obsolete by the application of computer algorithms.  the term is also used in other disciplines -- chemistry, geology, medicine, ...

Comment: BTW `\intercal` is not a TeX primitive or LaTeX command. It is defined by certain packages (`amssymb` for example). It would be better to read the documentation of those packages, rather than random shady sites like the one you linked to.

Comment: This was previously asked in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30619/what-is-the-best-symbol-for-vector-matrix-transpose/30632#comment757713_30632) on a [related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30632/134641). It [linked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30619/what-is-the-best-symbol-for-vector-matrix-transpose/30632#comment758502_30632) to a [page with some details](https://web.archive.org/web/20140731131646/http://planetmath.org/node/8095), but still without any real explanation.

Comment: Comments appreciated. Have researched intercalation now but still found no even part way clear description of that operator is does, and whence the symbol originated. That it's already in Unicode is noted and thanks for that, likewise that it's in a TeX package(s) and not a primitive. That said if it is genuinely considered off-topic by enough I'm happy to remove it of course, but put forth that the  reason I landed here (that this symbol comes highly recommended on many LaTeX pages as a transpose symbol) puts it into the TeX context for some (many?) of us I guess.

Comment: As an aside it is grouped here:

https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2200.pdf

with apparent logical operators XOR, NAND and NOR.  THis symbol remains a curio for me.

Comment: See [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) and search for `intercal`. There's a note below “Table 51: AMS Binary Operators” about the symbol. Elsewhere in the document too, it occurs as a binary operator, but not everywhere.

Comment: Yes, but I still wonder what binary operator. It seems one of the most elusive operator symbols I have ever come across. I'd like to see it in use somewhere I guess or clearly defined. It seems a symbol that worked its way into Unicode then into LaTeX apparently with a community of people completely unaware of what that symbol/operator does. I admit this whole question is slowly becoming obvious of scratching an itch to know something of the meaning and history of symbol we are widely using to denote transposes (because it does look nice).

Comment: I find `\intercal` completely unapt for the transpose: it's too low.

Comment: egreg, it's aptness is of course subjective. But if you search on-line for advice on how to indicate matrix transposes in TeX the web is littered with advice that \intercal is popular perhaps the most popular means of doing so.  To wit, give a wholly unrelated symbol is being recommended widely in the TeX for a novel (to its designers) use, I felt this burning question and suspect I am not alone.

Answer (score 23):

The earliest mention I can find is the SGML standard (1986) which lists `intcal` in its additional mathematical symbols list under "binary and large operators" the definition being (in full)

```
<!ENTITY intcal SDATA "[intcal]"--/intercal B: intercal-->
```

which means the the entity `&intcal;` could be used to make an unspecified system specific character (with as for all characters in this standard no encoding or pictorial clue what the character should look like). Note however the section heading and the **/B** in the entity definition comment both imply that the intended use is as a binary operator (which would imply that using it as a funky `T` for matrix transpose is a mis-use)

Unicode 1.0 added INTERCALATE at U+22BA  citing SGML `intcal` as a prior character

https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode1.0.0/ch06.pdf

In MathML we assigned alias `&intercal;` to this and defined it (as required by XML which does not have SDATA entities) to U+22BA so MathML defines

```
<!ENTITY intcal           "&#x022BA;" ><!--INTERCALATE -->
<!ENTITY intercal         "&#x022BA;" ><!--INTERCALATE -->
```

so both of names `&intcal;` and `&intercal;` work in MathML, and so in HTML since version 5, which incorporated the MathML entities.

Separately the AMS (AMS this time standing for American Mathematical Society, not the AMS in ISOAMSB which stands for ISO Additional Mathematical Symbols set B) produced the TeX AMS Fonts and assigned the character the name `\intercal` as a binary operator with definition (in its later latex2e form)

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intercal}     {\mathbin}{AMSa}{"7C}
```

The `unicode` math package keeps the `\intercal` name defining it, as in MathML, to be U+22BA, again as a binary operator

```
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"022BA}{\intercal                 }{\mathbin}{intercal}%
```

So U+22BA is intercal and looks like ⊺  which is sort of like a squashed dropped  sans serif T, not to be confused with T (U+0054) which looks like T, or top (U+22A4) which looks like ⊤.

As the editor of at least some of the specifications mentioned above I can confirm that the name has just been inherited without any actual knowledge of what the character is supposed to be used for.

Wikipedia suggests "intercalate" may be used in

[timekeeping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercalation_(timekeeping))

> Intercalation or embolism in timekeeping is the insertion of a leap day, week, or month into some calendar years to make the calendar follow the seasons or moon phases. Lunisolar calendars may require intercalations of both days and months.

[Chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercalation_(chemistry))

> In chemistry, intercalation is the reversible inclusion or insertion of a molecule (or ion) into materials with layered structures.

[University Admin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercalation_(university_administration))

> Intercalation, in the context of university administration, is a period when a student is allowed to officially take time away from studying for an academic degree.

But nowhere do I see any use of a symbol resembling T

Comment: Excellent and much appreciate research! I fall just shy of calling at an answer to the actual question preferring honestly to leave it flagged unanswered until (as a community) we have uncovered some actual intended use for the symbol I guess. As some have noted this is indeed rather peripheral to TeX if not entirely off topic, but if we stand any hope of someone showing up some day with reference on the intended use and origin of the symbol then it's worth keeping this pen unanswered I think.

There is a delicious hint here:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symbols:T

Comment: Some further observations on this. Clues we had to date are that it is often classed as a mathematical binary operator.  Interestingly it is mentioned mathematically in the context of [matrices](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.04981) but in the [Haskell](http://rigaux.org/language-study/syntax-across-languages-per-language/Haskell.html) programming language is a function akin to "join" in many other languages. I imagine the binary operation in math may thus have operated on lists much in the way join operates on lists? But have yet to find the slightest evidence of that.

Comment: Intercalation in biochemistry can refer to small molecules that insert themselves between  base-pairs in DNA. I imagine it has a general meaning of "insert this item/sequence into a another sequence here". I've also seen "⊺" used as a caret for "insert here" in proof-reading (though this appears to be non-standard).

Comment: If I correctly remember from undergraduate days, studying the construction of mathematical tables of functions, intercalation was used in noting a correction to a table entry.  So when this came up in the context of a requested symbol, the concept was not unfamiliar, although the symbol did not immediately "click".

Comment: I've just come across this sentence in a book I'm reading:  "These rare survivors from Earth's youth consist mostly of volcanic flows and ash, but thin intercalations of sediments enable us to ask about life's antiquity."  I think the meaning is clear, and conforms to my earlier understanding.  Intercalation = explicitly placed insertion.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old question, it came out at the top of my search for what this symbol is about so I thought I'd add what I found - according to the Online Etymology Dictionary (https://www.etymonline.com/word/intercalate) "intercalate" came from a term referring to the insertion of a calendar date to balance the Roman calendar which was done after the Terminalia (see also the link above by David Carlisle on timekeeping).

According to Wikipedia the Terminalia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminalia) was a festival in honor of the god Terminus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminus_(god)) the god who protected boundary markers and whose name was used in Latin as the word for boundary markers.

I couldn't find anything linking this to LaTeX, unicode, or any of the other references above, so the fact that there's a T involved might be just a coincidence, but it's been two years since this was posted so I'll offer it as possibly-maybe folklore that might be interesting to the trivia-minded sorts like myself.

Answer (score 1):

The term "intercalate" came up recently in the "Alpha Agora", a site devoted to words and their origins.  The "cal" is related to "calendar", and intercalation originally meant "insert an extra day in the calendar" (such as a leap year day).  So it's natural to extend the meaning to insertion of an appropriate term in a series, and that is how I became familiar with it, inserting new values in function tables.  The T-shaped symbol is a fairly obvious shape that can be set between two values to indicate an insertion.

The entry in the above-mentioned web forum that gives the details is
https://www.alphadictionary.com/bb/viewtopic.php?t=12346