# Increase size of symbol \intercal when in superscript position

Tags: math-mode, symbols, mtpro

Starting from this code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb} 
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
$(L\boldsymbol{\mathcal A}')^\intercal =\boldsymbol{\mathcal A}'{}^\intercal  L^\intercal $
\end{document}
```

with this output

[image]

I'd like to move the `\intercal` command a little higher and to the left in the direction indicated by the arrow. But does LaTeX have a direct command to move the symbol up or down or do I need to use specific macros? What could be the ways to have an adequate and beautiful way to write this formula?

Comment: I haven't the fonts but intercal is essentially a lowered sans serif T so `^{\mathsf{T}}` might look better

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Before I have used always `\top`. The last command is very thin and that's because I bet on `\intercal`.

Comment: Is `^\intercal` supposed to denote the transpose operator? Just curious.

Comment: @Mico I wrote an essay on that :-) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435328/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-name-of-the-intercal-symbol/435363#435363

Comment: @Mico +1 for your comment: yes of course.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle +1 for the history :-)

Answer (score 7):

Combining David's suggestion with Sebastiano's requirement...

I use `\mathsf{T}` as the core of the revised `\intercal` (you can rename it something else if you don't want to overwrite it), but then to make it smaller, I use it in cramped, superscripted form (revision 1).  Alternately, I just set it in `\scriptscriptstyle`, which lowers its elevation a bit, while still keeping it higher than the original `\intercal` (revision 2).

Original, then two revisions.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb} 
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}%[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
$(L\boldsymbol{\mathcal A}')^\intercal =\boldsymbol{\mathcal A}'{}^\intercal  L^\intercal $

\renewcommand\intercal{{\cramped{{}^\mathsf{T}}}}
$(L\boldsymbol{\mathcal A}')^\intercal =\boldsymbol{\mathcal A}'{}^\intercal  L^\intercal $

\renewcommand\intercal{\mathsf{\scriptscriptstyle T}}
$(L\boldsymbol{\mathcal A}')^\intercal =\boldsymbol{\mathcal A}'{}^\intercal  L^\intercal $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great Steven. But what is \cramped?

Comment: @Sebastiano `\cramped` is a style that takes less vertical space, by lowering superscripts.  It is automatically used, for example, for arguments of `\sqrt` (requires `amsmath`).

Comment: @Sebastiano I see.  I do not need `\cramped` in the 2nd revision.  I have removed it.

Comment: Hi, please, the comment that I have written to Mico. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another variation on David's idea to use `\mathsf{T}` instead of either `\intercal` or `\top`. The macro `\tp` (short for "transpose", naturally) employs `\scriptscriptstyle` math mode. The `\tp` macro takes an optional argument: a scalar number, to indicate how many `mu` the "T" should be shifted to the left. The ability to fine-tune the horizontal position can come in handy if you're dealing with letters, such as `L`, which have no component in the upper-right quadrant. (The default amount of left-shift is 3, as in `-3mu`. Aside: `\mkern-3mu` is the same as `\!`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\newcommand\bmcA{\boldsymbol{\mathcal A}'{}}
\newcommand\tp[1][3]{^{^{\mkern-#1mu\mathsf{T}}}}
\begin{document}
$\intercal$ $\top$ $\mathsf{T}$

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
$(L\bmcA)^\intercal = \bmcA{}^\intercal L^\intercal$ & \verb+\intercal+ \\
$(L\bmcA)^\top = \bmcA^\top L^\top$                  & \verb+\top+      \\
$(L\bmcA)\tp = \bmcA\tp L\tp = \bmcA{}\tp L\tp[6]$   & \verb+\tp+
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The answers are all very good. :-( If I don't give the green check it's because I'm good with the two answers at the same time.