# Typographic question regarding horizontal spacing in math, involving mathsf, mathsb, and superscripts

Tags: math-mode, spacing, typography

This might seem like a petty question, but sometimes, I do care about good typography.

In this expression:
`\mathsb{p}^\mathsf{T} A^{\mathsf{T}} A \mathsb{p}`
($ \mathsb{p}^{\mathsf{T}} A^\mathsf{T} A \mathsb{p} $)
looks a bit awkward typographically: the horizontal space between `A^T` and `A` is too much while the space between `A` and `p` is too small.

I know I could insert some `\!` and `\,` , but
how can I correct the somewhat awkward default spacing in general and more automatically?
(I can define macros for parts of the equations.)

Note, this question is not about superscripts or the (vertical) spacing of superscripts. It is about *horizontal* pacing, more specifically, about *automatic* ways of nice horizontal spacing (kerning?) in cases like the above.

Any ideas , insights , or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a very common question.  [See here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30619/125871).

Comment: `^\mathsf{T}` only compiles by coincidence. The correct syntax is `^{\mathsf{T}}`.

Comment: The normal notation for the transpose is a `lowercase t prescript`, which is easily obtained with the `leftidx`  package (`\ltrans` command).

Comment: The question cited by @SandyG is explicitly about the transpose symbol.  This question is about spacing.

Comment: I guess I should change the title, the old one might be misleading

Comment: @Bernard Perhaps in your French books. That's *not* the standard notation.

Comment: @egreg: Are you sure? I always thought Bourbaki was the standard reference as to typography in maths.

Comment: @Bernard Not at all.

Comment: Personally, I have never seen lowercase t prescript. See also Numerical Recipes or Gantmacher.